# How to separate a possessive adjective from its noun properly?

Tags: objects, possessive-adjectives

I will explain with examples.

> I sat between **her** and the door
>
> I sat between **her** and her bag.

"her" would mean the girl herself, in the first example, and it would still mean that in the second example.

> Because what only matters to me is that you didn't steal any of **her**
>   and her friend's money.

So, would "her" in the third example mean "herself" instead of "her money"? If yes, then how should I fix it?

I didn't write (her money and her friend's money) to avoid redundancy.

Comment: What do you mean by separate an object pronoun from its noun?? The first examples have no relation to the third one. The pronouns with self/selves are only for emphasizing the pronoun. I, myself, do not understand your question. her and her friend's money cannot be restated using herself.

Comment: What about replacing "her and her friend's money" by "their money" if you have already mentioned both previously? It's less verbose. :-)

Comment: @Lambie - I **explained** with examples, which means that the sentence I intend, the third example, wouldn't be as the above ones since they are for explanation purposes. "her money" is an object pronoun, and the question is essentially about it. I don't want to restate the sentence with "herself", I just don't want "her" to mean "herself".

Comment: @RubioRic - Thank you. The problem is that they are not mentioned previously, but I would rewrite the sentence with (their) if there is no other solution.

Comment: Herself can only be used to emphasize she.She, herself, did not understand the question. Pronouns with self are only for emphasis.

Comment: Reflexive pronouns are not only for emphasis. Sometimes they are obligatory complements, as in _She hurt herself_  /  _Ed was talking to himself_.

Comment: A lot of native speakers would be quite happy with ("non-possessive") *you didn't steal any of **her** and her friend's money*, where the possessive apostrophe in ***friend's*** applies *both* nouns. But quite a few (most?) would go for *...any of **hers** and her friend's money* anyway. And unquestionably the majority go with explicit possessive for *both* with the male equivalent....

Comment: ...see [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=him+and+his+friend%27s%2Chis+and+his+friend%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chim%20and%20his%20friend%20%27s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20and%20his%20friend%20%27s%3B%2Cc0) comparing ***...him / his** and his friend's*. Whatever - in none of these contexts would it be appropriate to think about including the reflexive forms ***herself / himself***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I can understand your point although "this chart" is not showing any plot as there's, according to his saying, no valid Ngrams to plot. However, the data is filled in the spaces. (him and his friend's,his and his friend's - 1800 to 2000 - smoothing of 3).

Comment: @TasneemZh: Oh. Don't know what's going on there. [I'll try again!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=him+and+his+friend%27s%2Chis+and+his+friend%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chim%20and%20his%20friend%20%27s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20and%20his%20friend%20%27s%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ...weird. I'm looking at the chart, but when I copy and past the address into a comment here and try to follow the link in another browser window, it says "nothing to plot". Summat to do with the possessive apostrophes, obviously.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It has appeared when I clicked on "Search lots of books". Clearly, "his and his friend's" is more popular and used than the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't steal any of her and her friend's money

There **her** is a possessive adjective.  her money, the money of her friend.

> I sat next to her.

There **her** is the objective case of subjective/nominative case  **she**.

The object of a preposition is typically in the objective case.

> ... with her, to her, beside her, of her, on her, under her, over her, in her etc.

Answer (score 0):

The word **her** can act as both a **possessive pronoun** and a **possessive adjective** (which is not true for the male equivalents him/his).

So, in the sentence:

> I sat between HER and HER bag

the first HER is a poossessive pronoun referring to the person herself and the second is a possessive adjective qualifying the bag that belongs to her.

In the sentence you query, the use of HER can only refer to the money owned by the person concerned because you can't steal any part of a person unless you are speaking metaphorically or stealing body parts.

Because of the context, there is no confusion. Equally, you could have written **any of her money and/or her friend's** or **her friend's money and hers**,

http://www.softschools.com/examples/grammar/possessive_adjectives_versus_possessive_pronouns_examples/82/

Comment: The first **her** isn't possessive but an oblique (objective) case. *I sat between **them** and **their** dog, at least I thought the dog was **theirs***.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I bow to your learning. I don't think they'd been invented when I was at university..

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: This exact situation doesn't seem to have come up on ELL, but I completely endorse [your ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/286518/2637) pointing out that ***Her and her boyfriend** used as the compound subject of a verb is "substandard" though not uncommon.*